# Count and compare boolean values using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I am trying to count the false count per item in `attentdanceList` from the code below. My goal is to only pick those items whose false count is greater than or equal to 2.

False count: the number of times an item has the attent.present as false.

```cs
var attentdanceList = 
    from attent in attentdance
    orderby attent.UpdatedOn descending
    where !attent.Present && attent.UpdatedOn >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-3)
    select new AttentdanceResponse
    {
        Id = attent.RowKey,
        SchoolId = attent.PartitionKey,
        StudentId = attent.StudentId,
        ClassRoomId = attent.ClassRoomId,
        TeacherId = attent.TeacherId,
        Latitude = attent.Latitude,
        Longitude = attent.Longitude,
        Present = attent.Present,
        Timestamp = (DateTime)attent.UpdatedOn
    };
```

The code above gives the following output:
[image]

Goal: to select only those items whose false count is >= 2.

Comment: What does this "false count" mean?

Comment: @steven the number of times an item has the attent.present as false

Comment: From what I understand, attent.Present is a boolean for each attent item. How can an item have this value false multiple times? Do you mean to count how many total items have "Present" false?

Comment: @MajdOdeh items are duplicated multiple times in the DB it is an attendance DB where each item has true and false representing absent or present multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a [GroupBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=net-6.0) to group the students together, and then count the present-boolean.

I created a snippet for you: https://dotnetfiddle.net/K9hFVo

```
        // Student collection
        IList<Student> studentList = new List<Student>()
        {
            new Student() { StudentID = 1, StudentName = "John", Present = true },
            new Student() { StudentID = 2, StudentName = "Ram", Present = false },
            new Student() { StudentID = 1, StudentName = "John", Present = false },
            new Student() { StudentID = 2, StudentName = "Ram", Present = true },
            new Student() { StudentID = 1, StudentName = "John", Present = false }
        };

        // LINQ Query Syntax to find out teenager students
        var groups = studentList.GroupBy(x => x.StudentID).Where(x => x.Count(y => !y.Present) >= 2);

        foreach (var studentGrouping in groups)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"studentid: " + studentGrouping.Key);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I may have misunderstood the question, but if you're trying to count how many items have `Present` as False, here is how you do it:

You can use the Method syntax of Linq instead of the SQL syntax:

```
var failCount = 0;

var attendanceList = attendance
   .OrderByDescending(attent => attent.UpdatedOn)
   .Where(attent => 
       {
           if(!attent.Present)
               failCount++;

           return !attent.Present && attent.UpdatedOn >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-3));
       })
   .Select(attent => new AttentdanceResponse
    {
        Id = attent.RowKey,
        SchoolId = attent.PartitionKey,
        StudentId = attent.StudentId,
        ClassRoomId = attent.ClassRoomId,
        TeacherId = attent.TeacherId,
        Latitude = attent.Latitude,
        Longitude = attent.Longitude,
        Present = attent.Present,
        Timestamp = (DateTime)attent.UpdatedOn
    })
   .ToArray();
```

Because of the way Linq does these things (i.e. the IEnumerable isn't actually processed until it is requested in the code), I think you would need to call `ToArray` (or `ToList` depending on what you need) at the end as well. Not 100% positive if it will affect the `failCount`, but it won't hurt to be sure by calling `ToArray`. `ToArray` forces the Linq statement to be executed by returning an array.